# Linear Algebra - Show that $M$ is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set of all 2 x 2 matrices where the product of the elements on the main diagonal is zero.

$$M = \left \lbrace\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \left. \right | a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R,ad = 0 \right \rbrace$$

Define addition and scalar multiplication on $M$ in the usual way.

Show that $M$, with respect to these operations of addition and scalar multiplication, is **not** a vector space by showing that **one** of the vector space axioms does not hold.

To be honest, I don't know how to perform addition and scalar multiplication to solve this question. If anyone could explain exactly how to solve this, that would be great!

Comment: Is the set closed under addition?

Comment: @Tpofofn yeah it is

Comment: @Raba are you sure about that?

Comment: So $\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$ are in the set.  Is their sum in the set?

Comment: @Casteels I was told so, although, I am not clear on this topic

Comment: "You were told so"?? Since when that claiming things in mathematics gets reinforced by "being told so"??

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 1  \\
 \end{array} \right) $ and $B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1  \\
1 & 0  \\
 \end{array} \right) $ be two matrices in M. Then $$A+B=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2  \\
2 & 1  \\
 \end{array} \right) $$ does not belong in M.

Comment: R, this is something I really badly want to understand. I know this is years after your response, I am just really trying to understand vector spaces. Why does it not belong to M, is it because neither of the diagonals are 0 and are 1? What kind of matrices would then be vector spaces? I still can't fully wrap my head around it

Comment: @bernando_vialli Vector spaces are closed under summation. But here, the sum $A+B$ does not satisfy the condition of being $M$: namely, the product of the diagonal elements is $1\times 1=1\neq 0$ as required to be in $M$. What kind of matrices would be vector spaces? Well, some matrices that satisfy some condition which remains invariant to summation and scalar multiplication for instance.

Comment: Thank you!!! I think I am still confused. When you say 1 * 1 = 1 diagonal elements instead of so you are referring to the A+B matrix in your response? What if say that matrix was [0 2 2 0] instead of [1 2 2 1] would that make it a vector space? I guess I am quiet confused why does the diagonal have to be 0? How do you construct the 2 matrices in your example, did you basically pick 2 matrices as long as the A11 = 0 and B22 = 0? Like alternatively A can be [0 20 20 20] and [50 50 50 0] right? Sorry I have been reviewed quiet similar examples in a book and don't follow the answers.